# A C program demonstrating how cmd.exe and a linux shell e.g. bash, delimit parameters?

Tags: c, windows, linux, command-line, cmd

I have heard that the cmd shell passes the entire thing to the command, and then a standard C library delimits it, taking into account spaces and quotes. And that in linux just the shell does it.

A program with a while loop, displaying argsv[i] shows how it gets delimited, but not what is done by the shell, and what is done by the C library.

Can anybody point me to or show me a program that would show it?

Comment: Why do you think what you've described doesn't tell you what the shell does and what the program must do?

Comment: I said, standard library. I was under the impression that once it get to the main method, the argsv has been delimited by a library. no?

Comment: The libc doesn't do anything.

Comment: If you want to investigate what the C runtime does on a given platform, I would suggest investigating at the assembly level - your question could be generalised to be "how does an operating system execute a program?".

Comment: @CoteButcher this is not a general question.. the question is what it is. and  maybe there are some people here that know, and know of how it can be demonstrated.

Comment: @Ignacio: On Windows it does. A process on Windows just gets a command line, not individual arguments.

Comment: @Joey Can you demonstrate that the c standard library is doing it in windows? like perhaps a way of showing what it is after the shell has been at it, and before the standard library has split it?

Comment: @barlop: Processes in Windows get a command line as a single string. C programs get an array of strings for delimited arguments in their `main` function. As you already noticed, for the MS libc this happens in `stdargv.c`.

Comment: somebody mentioned stdargv.c to me once to me a while back.. I am new to c..  I still would like to be able to demonstrate... as I said, that the c library does it in windows.. a way of showing what it is after the shell has been through it and before the c library has split it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you want to know how the shell works in linux right? I think that when we type anything on the command shell, the shell receives all the argument as parameters in string format, shell then fork+exec the binary and pass all the arguments as environment variable to new binary, these environment variable is then put into the stack of the new process by the kernel and which is later access as argc and argv[] by the process but no special processing done by c library.

Comment: thanks, i'm interested in how that contrasts with how it is done in windows.. and ideally a program that demonstrates that.

Comment: Hi barlop, The stack setting(argument setting) is done by the kernel and not done in the application , thus it is difficult to demonstrate through programme but you can use strace in linux to trace the complete flow of executeion, But i have no idea how it can be done in Windows, I have no knowledge in windows :-)

Comment: on a windows system I just downloaded and tried stracent(found googling for strace for windows!), I tried stracent on a program that just takes param and displays them.  but it wasn't very revealing! http://pastebin.com/gtb7x2L2

Comment: hmmm.. ok then other way is to debug through the CRT that is the code which calls the main function(at least in Linux), So may be compile the code with -g and use gdb to dissemble and put a break on __libc_start_main which in turn calls the main, I hope this should help to see how things work.

Answer (score 1):

On any POSIX or POSIX-like operating system, the standard library has nothing to do with parsing the command line into components. It's done entirely by the shell. The POSIX `exec` family of functions takes an array of pointers, just like `main` receives. Usually it will be the kernel's responsibility to cleanly arrange and preserve these in a special location (top of the stack is typical) across `exec` (when the previous program's address space is obliterated).

As for **how** to do what the shell does, it's straightforward albeit painful as soon as you read a detailed explanation of what the shell does. You can find that here:

http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption that Windows cmd.exe and the Linux shell work the same is incorrect. Try doing `echo *` on both systems - Windows will display `*`, Linux will display a list of files in the current directory.

The Windows program will receive `*` in `argv[1]` and nothing else. The Linux program will receive a number of elements in `argv`, each one being a complete file name including spaces if any.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0;  i < argc;  ++i)
    {
        printf("%d: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where did I assume that the linux shell and cmd.exe work the same?  I know about * But that has nothing to do with delimiting parameters to a command with space and quotes defining which parameter is which. Anyhow, I am asking about a program demonstrating how they delimit parameters differently. So no, I do not assume they work the same. And I know about *, it has nothing to do with my question.  If my question was based on any assumption, it is that they don't work the same.

Comment: @barlop, sorry if I misinterpreted the question, I think it was the title that misled me. As for how much is done by the shell and how much is done by the C library, it's hard to demonstrate via a program since all this has occurred before the program starts.